# TranslateTransition JavaFX

Tags: user-interface, animation, javafx, translate

I am trying to implement a TranslateTransition to my rectangle but it doesn´t do anything at all.
Here is my code:

```
primaryStage.setTitle("AnimationTest");
    Group group = new Group();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
    group.getChildren().add(rect);
    TranslateTransition transition =new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000),rect);
        transition.setByX(100);

    Button button = new Button("StartAnimation");
        button.setOnAction((e)->{
            transition.play();
        });
    VBox layout = new VBox();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(group, button);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for `Group`:

> A Group will take on the collective bounds of its children

In other words, as the rectangle moves, the coordinate system of the group adjusts to fit everything it contains. Since the only thing it contains is the rectangle, the rectangle remains fixed with respect to the group's container.

Use a `Pane` instead of the `Group`:

```
primaryStage.setTitle("AnimationTest");
Pane pane = new Pane();

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
pane.getChildren().add(rect);
TranslateTransition transition =new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000),rect);
    transition.setByX(100);

Button button = new Button("StartAnimation");
    button.setOnAction((e)->{
        transition.play();
    });
VBox layout = new VBox();
layout.getChildren().addAll(pane, button);
Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```